# 22.04.3 LTS Desktop *-network UNCLAIMED

Tags: networking, drivers, macbook

I recently set my 2018 Mac book pro to dual boot using 22.04.3 LTS Desktop and it wont allow me to connect to the internet via WiFi. When I enter

> sudo lshw -C network

it gives me this:

```
*network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network controller
    product: BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
    physical id:0
    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
    version: 03
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciecpress cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    reasources: memory:81400000-8140fff memory:81000000-813fffff
```

I haven't tried any trouble shooting attempts outside of looking through the system settings. I assume its some issues with the drivers since I am now learning this is quite common.

Thank you for any help in advanced!

Comment: Thanks for the pointer I made an edit. I use Ubuntu Desktop.